# Convert slurm accounting output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, slurm

I'm looking for a way to get the elapsed time output to always include days, at the moment I can't see away in defining an output format so I'm looking at using cut, awk, sed or similar command(s) to do this after the output has been generated.

So any ideas how I can change output such as:

```
JobID|Partition|User|State|Elapsed|
902464|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|10-00:10:40
968491|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|12:49:20
970801|interactive-a|sam|COMPLETED|07:00:46
912973|interactive-a|tom|COMPLETED|41-02:34:41
971356|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|04:36:35
971912|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|02:12:02
972668|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|00:09:06
```

Into this format (the last column has 0- added where needed)

```
JobID|Partition|User|State|Elapsed|
902464|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|10-00:10:40|
968491|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|0-12:49:20|
970801|interactive-a|sam|COMPLETED|0-07:00:46|
912973|interactive-a|tom|COMPLETED|41-02:34:41|
971356|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-04:36:35|
971912|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-02:12:02|
972668|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-00:09:06|
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/|\([0-9:]\{1,\}\)$/|0-\1/' file
JobID|Partition|User|State|Elapsed|
902464|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|10-00:10:40
968491|interactive-a|bob|COMPLETED|0-12:49:20
970801|interactive-a|sam|COMPLETED|0-07:00:46
912973|interactive-a|tom|COMPLETED|41-02:34:41
971356|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-04:36:35
971912|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-02:12:02
972668|interactive-a|mat|COMPLETED|0-00:09:06
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '$5 ~ /-|E/ || ($5 = "0-" $5) && gsub(/ /,"|")' file
```

- `-F\|` set `FS` to `|`
- `$5 ~ /-|E/` matches and prints records with `-` OR `E` in fifth field
- `||` logical OR, ie. if previous didn't match, then:
- `($5 = "0-" $5)` prepend `0-` to fifth field
- `&& gsub(/ /,"|")` AND replace those space-replaced field separators with `|`s.
- above could be removed if `-v OFS="|"` was used:

  $ awk -v OFS=\| -F\| '$5 ~ /-|E/ || ($5 = "0-" $5)' file

  $ awk -v OFS=\| -F\| '$5 ~ /-|E/ || ($5 = "0-" $5)' file

Comment: Why doesn't the `{}` work on the latter `$ awk` line after the bullets? (feel free to play around with it).

Comment: @EdMorton That the `$ awk` starting line below the last bullet wouldn't turn to `code line` with `{}` or quad spacing it.